# PHP gethostbyname security implications

Tags: web-application, appsec, php

I'm working on a PHP application.
There is a requirement to find IP's by hostname and i have to resort to gethostbynamel for that.
Looks like there is no other way.

I was wondering if there are any security implications related to this.
I am validating the hostname given as input from end-user by using regular expressions.

I have two options:

1. When user submits a form with hostname, validate it and use `gethostbynamel`
2. When user submits a form with hostname, validate it store it in database and use cron job which runs `gethostbynamel`

Will there be any difference in the above methods?

Security is top priority for the application.

Comment: What is the reasoning for getting the IP? Is it like a reverse lookup? What types of hosts are you expecting?

Comment: @mikemackintosh In my application, licensing is based on IP's. So if user enters hostname, i need to get IP's to calculate licenses consumed.

Answer (score 1):

The php function `gethostbynamel` is a wrapper over the native OS `gethostbyname` function.
The implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/dns.c#L233).

So the same vulnerabilities that apply to the `gethostbyname` syscall will apply to your code.
I don't see any existing `gethostbyname` vulnerabilities that would bother me.

So basically as long as you are validating the hostnames accurately, you should be fine.
See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824105/844579) and [this text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) for help on regex.

Amongst the two options you posted, they don't make any difference so far as the security implications are concerned. `gethostbyname` is a network call, so there is a non-negligible time associated with it. This can be one of the differentiators why you'd choose to use one over the other.